# MySQL PHP Display Text if Value is 1

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a PHP script where text is displayed if the MySQL row id=1 has an entry of 1 in the value field and no text is shown if it has a different value. The script I wrote so far doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php

    // connect to the database
    include('connect-db.php');

?>
<?php  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Cups WHERE id='1'"); if           
($row_queryname['value'] == '1') {?> 
Display text here.
<?php }?>
```

I am quite new at this so any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use one of the "fetch" functions to actually get a row after you make a query.  Since you haven't specified any field names, I'm going to use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php):

```
<?php
    // connect to the database
    include('connect-db.php');

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Cups WHERE id='1'");
    $ar = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($ar['fieldname'] == '1')  // Whatever your field name is
    {
?>
Display text here.
<?php
    }
?>
```

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` gets an associative array that represents a result row, where the array keys are the field names.

Note: This example does not include any error checking.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both.
[See More about mysql_fetch_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

```
<?php
    // connect to the database
    include('connect-db.php');

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Cups WHERE id='1'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    if ($result['value'] == '1') 
    {
        echo "your text here";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're just missing a step or two.  Here's a very simple way to do it.  Don't forget to check if your query returned any rows, and also remember that mysql_fetch_assoc() returns an array of rows, not just a single row (even if that array only contains a single row).

```
<?php

    // connect to the database
    include('connect-db.php');

?>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Cups WHERE id='1'");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    // $rows is an array of associative arrays
    if ($rows[0]['value'] == '1') {
        ?>
        Display text here.
        <?php
    }
?>
```